# Create new post if not already exist

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a bit of a problem in WordPress. I'm looping through a set of data and creating new posts. I need a way to only create the post if its already not exists.

I tried this, but figured it was a quite stupid idea. But can i do something similar? I cant check the titles, since they in many cases will be the same. Can i do the check on `import_id` somehow? If i do `$post_id->import_id` its undefined..

Current code:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < count($postdata); $i++) { //array of data.

    $id = rand(1000, 9999);

    if(is_null(get_post($id))) {
      $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
        'import_id' => $id, //number
        'post_status' => $post_status, //string
        'post_type' => $post_type, //string
        'post_title' => $post_title, //string
        'post_content' => $post_content //string
      ));
    }
  }
```

Comment: For comparing two posts, you have to have a unique field. It's usually the title field but in your case, you said most of titles are the same! hmmm, intersting! How about their content? The content is random too or is it something unique? Can you check on their content?

Comment: Ideally would be to compare import_id, but im not sure of how to implement that, since the post_id is undefined. was thinking if(!post_id->import_id).. create post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [post_exists()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/) it will check based on title. check the code below.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($postdata); $i++) { //array of data.

    $id         = rand(1000, 9999);
    $fount_post = post_exists( $post_title );

    if( !$fount_post ) {

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'import_id'    => $id, //number
            'post_status'  => $post_status, //string
            'post_type'    => $post_type, //string
            'post_title'   => $post_title, //string
            'post_content' => $post_content //string
        ) );

    }

}
```

**Update** as per OP code.

```
$events       = json_decode($res,true);
$this->events = $events['Result'];  
$postdata     = array();
$index        = 0;

foreach($this->events as $key=>$event) {
    $post_status = 'publish';
    $post_type = EVENTS_CALENDAR_POST_TYPE;
    $post_title = $event['Heading'];
    $post_content = $event['Description'];
    $post_image = $this->media_url . $event['ImageLarge']['Path'];
    $post_thumb = $this->media_url . $event['Image']['Path'];
    $post_event_id = $event['Id'];

    foreach($this->events[$key]['Dates'] as $date) {
        $post_date = substr($date['Date'], 0, 10);
        $post_arena = $date['Arena']['Name'];
        $postdata[$index]['id'] = $index;
        $postdata[$index]['status'] = $post_status;
        $postdata[$index]['posttype'] = $post_type;
        $postdata[$index]['date'] = $post_date;
        $postdata[$index]['arena'] = $post_arena;
        $postdata[$index]['heading'] = $post_title;
        $postdata[$index]['desc'] = $post_content;
        $postdata[$index]['image'] = $post_image;
        $postdata[$index]['thumb'] = $post_thumb;
        $index++;
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($postdata); $i++) { //array of data.

    $id = rand(1000, 9999);
    
    $args = array(
       'meta_key' => 'post_event_id'
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'post_event_id',
               'value' => $post_event_id,
               'compare' => '=',
           )
       )
    );

    $event = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( !$event->have_posts() ) {

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'import_id'    => $id, //number
            'post_status'  => $post_status, //string
            'post_type'    => $post_type, //string
            'post_title'   => $post_title, //string
            'post_content' => $post_content, //string
            'meta_input'   => array(
                'post_event_id' => $post_event_id,
            )
        ) );

    }

}
```

Comment: hi! as i said, i cant, since the titles are not unique.

Comment: @mathias5 where do you said it?

Comment: Hi! In my initial post. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: Then based on what you want to check posts exist or not?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And i cant check against the title, or content since they sometimes are the same, dont ask me why, but thats the solution i needed to go with. i need to check against something else. like an id or something.

Comment: You can check against id but what if once all will be used between `1000, 9999`?

Comment: Exactly. Thats the problem.. :)

Comment: would be great to do something like "if(!post_id->import_id)", but not sure how to implement since the post_id then will be undefined.

Comment: Then I think there is no way to do it. There needs to be uniqueness.

Comment: Yes, but how can i acheive that?

Comment: if the title and content will be the same then why need to be unique.

Comment: the posts gets its data from an API that returns events. Many events are the same but happens on different dates. so i create one post per date the event occurs. there for the title and content is the same.

Comment: Then leave as it is. what's the problem.

Comment: that's once the loop gets rund again it will create new posts so there will be duplicates.

Comment: No, i do not, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230795/discussion-between-bhautik-and-mathias5).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_post_status()` function to tell if a post exists. It will return false if the post does not exist:

```
if ( get_post_status( $id ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

With your example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($postdata); $i++) { //array of data.

    $id = rand(1000, 9999);

    if ( get_post_status($id) ) {
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
          'import_id' => $id, //number
          'post_status' => $post_status, //string
          'post_type' => $post_type, //string
          'post_title' => $post_title, //string
          'post_content' => $post_content //string
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case $id is coming from $id = rand(1000, 9999);

Comment: yes, thanks! the problem then is that it will continue to generate new id's and there fore create more posts than the lenght of the array i looping.

Comment: I am not sure how your import is structured, but you can use the post_exists() function to check against the title text. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/

Comment: that i cant, since some of the titles are the same. there fore i need something that is 100% specific to check against.

Comment: And the loop rund everytime a user visits the page, so the id cant change, like mine.